# How do I make my UserControl double buffered AND transparent?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My control is double buffered to improve performance, and I need to make it transparent (or, more precisely, I need to prevent it from overwriting parent's background). However, all methods I've tried (overriding OnPaintBackground, setting ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor and BackColor=Transparent) only make my control's background black.
Any ideas how to achieve my goal?

UPD sample code to play with:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;

        UpdateStyles();

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, Width / 2, Height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, no, that's not a problem.  We can't see what you are doing wrong when you don't show us.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I obviously can't show you all my code. I've already described what methods I've tried, though.

Comment: Does SetStyle append the style or do you need to do `SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor | ControlStyles.Opaque, true)`? I never have used it so I don't know.

Comment: Turning on ControlStyles.Opaque is wrong, delete it to fix your problem.  While you're at it, delete all of the styles code and just use `this.DoubleBuffered = true;`

Comment: @Hans Passant, 1 - wrong. 2 - doesn't change anything.